# Spring Cloud stream connecting to RabbitMQ thrown the following error: an unexpected connection driver error occurred

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

While the consumer tries to connect a remote RabbitMQ instance using Spring Cloud Stream the following exception is thrown
**c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler: An unexpected connection driver error occurred**

````
java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:288) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:91) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:184) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:598) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_202]```


**Configuration**

springCloudVersion --> **Hoxton.SR1**
org.springframework.boot --> **version '2.2.5.RELEASE**
dependency  --> **spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit**

**properties**

spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=eaudit

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.auditinputchannel.destination=auditchannel

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.auditinputchannel.group=auditqueue

Does anyone has had this issue?

Thanks
````

Comment: `>java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed` - the server closed the socket for some reason; possibly an authentication problem - look in the server log for the reason.

Comment: Thank you Gary, I noticed that virtual hosts state in the server is not running

Comment: I was pointing to the wrong port, my fault! lol

Comment: Fixing the port worked for me as well. Use 5672 instead of 15672 which is the port for the RabbitMQ Management UI.